# Python function producing unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables, output

I have the following python code:

```
from time import time


def program1(a,b):
    for trial in range(5):
        start = time()
        a + b
        print (time() - start)
program1(27,59)
```

and according to the tutorial should produce this output:

```
9.53674316406e-07
2.14576721191e-06
2.14576721191e-06
3.09944152832e-06
9.53674316406e-07
```

Instead it produces:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
>>>
```

I am trying to use it demonstrate the concept of time/space complexity.

Can anyone shed any light on the output and why it is not accepting the parameters?

Comment: a+b is happening too fast to have any resolution when time() - start is computed.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can achieve the output as shown in the tutorial in order to demonstrate this to students, or a better way perhaps that demonstrates

Comment: Use something more complex than `a+b`.

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` will create output that is ~1

Comment: @Barmar - but the tutorial (Harvard) suggests that output...what am I missing?

Comment: If you want to demonstrate time complexity, do something whose time is dependent on `trial`

Comment: They were probably doing it on a slower computer.

Comment: @balderman, could you say where time.sleep(1) goes

Comment: In place of `a + b`.

Comment: Instead of `a+b`

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: @Barmar - any suggestions

Comment: change `from time import time` to `import time`

Comment: Use `a**b` instead of `a+b`.

Comment: import time doesn't work -     start = time()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: a**b  - with the same inputs, still produces 0s

Comment: That's a baaad tutorial. Can you share the link to it?

Comment: Don't have the link unfortunately, but that bit is exactly as explained in the question. Are there any super ones for Big O demo - kid friendly?

Comment: I guess it's Activity 1 [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TZcKVFYVFDPEBnYPr4nCerz0PrXKrp07WbMWqlT8E4A/mobilebasic)? Anyway, the problem is mainly using the `time()` function, especially if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from time import time, sleep
import random


def program1(a,b):
    for trial in range(5):
        start = time() # gets current time

        time_to_sleep = random.random() # random() returns a number between 0 and 1
        
        # sleep will block the execution here for the number of seconds passed (0.5 is half a second for instance).
        sleep(time_to_sleep) 
        print (time() - start)
program1(27,59)
```

I added the random to make it a little bit unpredictable.

Comment: Rafael - will try - could you add some comments (for teaching purposes). Explaining what is happening. For instance, what exactly is time() doing (calling what).    and the sleep.random